# Exchange digits to reformat dates

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Input:

> Job1 07/09/2018 22:40:57  01/20/2019 11:48:52
>   Job2 11/28/2018 19:23:49  01/20/2019 05:29:49

Expected output:

> Job1 2018/09/07 22:40:57  2019/20/01 11:48:52
>   Job2 2018/28/11 19:23:49  2019/20/01 05:29:49

Change text from **dd/mm/yyyy** to **yyyy/mm/dd**, i.e replace the text

Comment: Pay for your needs

Comment: I did not understand, don't downvote simply..!

Comment: @VishwanathDalawai I am not the downvoter, but I expect it's because you haven't provided any details of what you have tried so far. Please edit the question to include that information as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

```bsh
$ echo -e "Job1 07/09/2018 22:40:57 01/20/2019 11:48:52\nJob2 11/28/2018 19:23:49 01/20/2019 05:29:49" | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)\/\([0-9]\+\)\/\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' -
Job1 2018/09/07 22:40:57 2019/20/01 11:48:52
Job2 2018/28/11 19:23:49 2019/20/01 05:29:49
```

### `sed` command explained:

`'s/pattern/replacement/'` this is the basic syntax

When we put a `g` at the end (like `'s/pattern/replacement/g'`) it will do multiple replacements on one line.

`[0-9]` matches any one digit.

`[0-9]*` matches zero or more digits.

`[0-9]\+` matches one or more digits (note: the backslash `\` is an escape character; in this example we needed to escape `+`, because otherwise the `bash` would interpret it, not `sed`; also note that in other circumstances/uses it does not have to be escaped).

`\/` is a slash `/`; again it must be escaped, but now because of `sed`, because we used `/` as separator around and between `pattern` and `replacement`; we could use any other character (like `'s@pattern@replacement@'` and then we would not need to replace the slashes `/`, but the at `@` character (or any other character we used as separator).

`[0-9]\{4\}` matches 4 digits; again `{` and `}` must be escaped because of `bash`.

([0-9]) matches any one digit and ‘saves’ it for later (to memory); then, in replacement we can use this matched substring that is enclosed in brackets `(` and `)` (in this case a single digit). Again, we needed to escape them because of `bash`.

`\1` is the first saved substring (see the previous paragraph); likewise `\2` is the second one and `\3` is the third one.

Therefore:
`\([0-9]\+\)\/\([0-9]\+\)\/\([0-9]\{4\}\)` matches a date in `dd/mm/yyyy` or `d/m/yyyy` format.

`\3\/\2\/\1` is a replacement, which consists of `\3` (the third substring, the year), `\/` is a slash, `\2` (the second substring, the month), again `\/` (a slash), and finally `\1` (the first substring, the day of month).